# Javascript causing multiple iterations through a custom page base in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, load

I have searched for an answer and am at the end of the rope.  I have a custom page base, when the head section has a script tag with a javascript onload(), the page base gets reloaded again for each one. If there are 4, the page goes through the overrides in the base the first time, the findcontrols all load, i insert some dynamic controls, and everything is great, then it cycles through the base again 4 more times.

```
PartialCachingControl ucHeader = (PartialCachingControl)Page.LoadControl("App_Controls/BaseHeaderControl.ascx");
HtmlContainerControl divHeader = (HtmlContainerControl)FindControl("divHeader");

if (divHeader != null && ucHeader != null)
{
    divHeader.Controls.Add(ucHeader);

    if (ucHeader.Controls.Count == 0)
    {
        divHeader.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The first time everything is right, I can find the controls in the usercontrol, and it runs beautifully, the second time, usercontrol controls are 0.  SO, its not causing a problem on the page, because it cycles through, then ignores it, and continues.

Without any javascript it works perfectly.

The main problem is, I'm trying to make divs with no content not visible, so when I set (pseudo) if usercontrol control equals 0 usercontrol visible equals false, it isnt false the first time, but the second and subsequent times it is false, so it always ends up being false.

help.

Comment: Have you considered simply wrapping your content in an `ASP:Panel` or `ASP:PlaceHolder` control and setting `Visible` to `true`/`false` as needed? I know it's not an answer to your question, but sometimes manipulating HTML controls by hand can get icky-sticky because the page-life-cycle gets involved. I'm wondering if that's what's happening here.

Comment: Can you post the javascript that is loaded?

Comment: It was any javascript or css, and I solved it by configuring IgnoreRoute on the folder with the css or javascript files. Worked like a charm.  1 minute of work solved about 100 headaches.

Comment: @Daniel, you can actually post an answer to your own question.  Perfectly acceptable to do so, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851/205305.